Noncommutative analogue of ring of integers in number field
I'm studying Igor V. Nikolaev's paper "Untying knots in 4D and Wedderburn’s theorem". In the paper, he works with hyper-algebraic fields $\mathbb{K}$, i.e., fields with noncommutative multiplication (division rings). The ring of integers of this field (division ring) is denoted by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}}$.
I am familiar with algebraic number theory and know that in that context, number fields are $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoined with the root of some monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ and that the ring of integers is the intersection of that field with the ring of algebraic integers, i.e., roots of monic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$.
In Lemma 3.1 of the paper, the author describes $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}}$ a being generated by the zeroes of a noncommutative polynomial with coefficients coming from $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{L}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is a finite dimensional extension of $\mathbb{L}$. The construction seems self-referent. I want to familiarize myself with these analogues of number fields and ring of integers but I don't know where to start. I've heard of an order in ring theory. Is that what this is? Any help is greatly appreciated.


Watch out: the sum of two elements in $\mathbb K$ integral over $\mathbf Z$ need not be integral over $\mathbf Z$.  There is no such thing as a single maximal order in $\mathbb K$. There are multiple maximal orders.  See http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/SC9-Orders.pdf to read about the case where $\mathbb K$ is a quaternion algebra (dimension $4$).
